# Facing problem while Running two DOM statements in if statement

Tags: javascript

I want both of DOM statements in  if/else statement being applied to both elements, But the first display style get applied the second won't

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("head")[0].display = "none";
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 1 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("head").style.display = "none"
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0].style.top = "90px";
  } else if (document.body.scrollTop < 10 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 10) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("head").style.display = "block"
    document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav")[0].style.top = "180px";
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add the html code?

Comment: If the first condition matches, the `else if` will not execute. If you want that behaviour you need to separate your conditions in to two *separate* `if` statements. Alternatively, make the conditions mutually exclusive.

Comment: Also note that the question does appear to have anything to do with Java, HTML, CSS, ReactJS or jQuery. It's pure Javascript, so I've retagged it for you. Please only include relevant tags in future.